# Obter index de trás para frente

Tags: c#, string

Imagine que tenho a seguinte string:

```
string texto = "Stackoverflow em Português";
```

Se eu quiser saber o index do primeiro espaço, basta:

```
int index = texto.IndexOf(" ");
```

Mas neste caso tenho dois espaços, e gostaria obter o index do último.

> É necessário considerar que a string pode ter mais espaços. O objetivo
>   é obter sempre o último.

Existe algo pronto em C# que faça isso?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Utilize o [LastIndexOf(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1wdsy8fy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string texto = "Stackoverflow em Português";

Console.WriteLine(texto.LastIndexOf(" "));
```

Saída: 16